# How to count the number of occurences of a char in a string in Bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, grep, character

**This is the code:**

```
#bash/bin
echo "Enter a sentence:"
read -e -a sentence
char="k"
echo "${sentence}" | awk -F"${char}" '{print NF-1}'
```

**Problem:**

It returns this error:

> ': not a valid identifier sentence -1

**Sample Input**

```
Enter a sentence:
thanks and okay
```

**Sample Output**

```
2
```

**Question:**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus just put in the edits may you review it for me? Thank you.

Comment: You want to count how often a certain character appears in a sentence?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: You aren't really searching for the character (which would imply you care about what position(s) `k` appears in); you are simply counting the number of occurrences.

Comment: @chepner right thank you, I meant to change the title, it was misleading.

Comment: #bash/bin -> #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 1):

Just strip everything *but* `$char`, then count the results.

```
echo "Enter a sentence:"
read -e sentence
char="k"
filtered=${sentence//[^$char]/}  # Delete anything *not* a $char
echo "${#filtered}"              # Output the length of filtered
```

Using standard shell, you need a pair of external utilities instead `bash`'s parameter substitution operator.

```
echo "$sentence" | tr -cd "$char" | wc -c
```

Comment: I tried this but it still returns the same error but with a 1 instead of a -1, did it work on your end?

Comment: Remove the `-a` from the call to `read`; you don't need an array for this.

Comment: As an array, `$sentence` is equivalent to `${sentence[0]}`, so you were only working with the first word from your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
#bash/bin
OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\0' # change IFS for avoid issue with spaces
read -a sentence -p "Enter a sentence: "
IFS=$OLDIFS # IFS old value
char="k"
grep -o '.' <<< "$sentence" |  grep "$char" | wc -l # first grep explode string characters, second grab character, wc count occurrences
```